# AttributeError: 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute '_browser'

Tags: browser, attributeerror

I'm trying to use TikTokApi for my django + react project to scrape data and save it. But when I ran the quickstart guide found in the TikTokApi docs, I was consistently getting the error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/TikTokApi/tiktok.py", line 635, in shutdown
AttributeError: 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute '_browser'
```

Here is the code:

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

with TikTokApi() as api:
    for trending_video in api.trending.videos(count=5):
        # Prints the author's username of the trending video.
        print(trending_video.author.username)
```

I am using the latest version of playwright and TikTokApi (5.2.2). I even tried using puppeteer. I have reviewed the docs and other websites multiple times. Does this have anything to do with playwright Chromium?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[EDIT]: I just made my own selenium scraper instead.

Comment: Do you have a github with your selenium scraper?